# Add a edit button on the page of a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I would like to add a button Edit to validate changes made on this page. 
For the moment, I managed to view the contents of the post meta without opportunity to change the values on this page.

Thanks for your help.

[page of a custom post type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRJXW.png)